# LaTeX Error: \begin{tcolorbox} on input line x ended by \end{myenv} when using new environment

Tags: macros, environments

Defining a new environment with a tcolorbox with some options strangely leads to a compilation failure that disappears if I remove `[hbox]`

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{\begin{tcolorbox}[hbox]}
  {\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
  blah
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

I can't define `\tcbset{capture=hbox}` because it's the only option that's protected from tcbset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases in environments, you need to use the macro form `\tcolorbox` and `\endtcolorbox`, instead of the standard `\begin...\end` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myenv}
{\tcolorbox[hbox]}
  {\endtcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
  blah
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, well, ok. Is there a reason for that? :D Thanks!

Comment: @Lhooq on further research, I believe the reason is that, when using `\begin{tcolorbox}` format, it searches the *input stream* for `\end{tcolorbox}`, which it will not find (it only finds `\end{myenv}`).  Using the macro form eliminates the search for `\end{tcolorbox}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried adding `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` but came up with the same problem but `\centering` seems to work. Maybe it would be better to define a custom tcolorbox

Comment: @Lhooq Inside an environment, `\centering` is preferred to `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, even if the latter works, because the latter adds extraneous space that only makes sense if it is the outer environment.

Comment: Ok, I got it :-)
I have a last question (I hope). If I use the package verbatim and add \verbatim and \endverbatim it stops working with the following error `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`. Does it mean I can't use multiple \env \endenv?

Comment: @Lhooq `verbatim` is the trickiest of all environments in LaTeX, because it changes the catcodes of all the "special" characters.  It is not trivial to embed it within other environments.  Often, if your goal is to develop some sort of special-purpose verbatim environment, you should first look to other packages that specialize in verbatim environments.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot :-)