# Custom environment for tcolorbox not working with certain option

Tags: equations, errors, environments, tcolorbox, highlighting

I have trouble defining a custom environment for a tcolorbox equation environment. When I define an environment for my *tcolorbox* with *ams align* Option I get the error:

```
LaTeX Error: \begin{tcolorbox} on input line 494 ended by \end{myenv}. (\end{myenv}
```

With the answer from [LaTeX Error: \begin{tcolorbox} on input line x ended by \end{myenv} when using new environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563230/latex-error-begintcolorbox-on-input-line-x-ended-by-endmyenv-when-using-n) I thought I could solve it. But while the example from this question works, mine doesn't.

So it works to use this environment

```
 \newenvironment{myenv}
 {\tcolorbox[hbox]}
   {\endtcolorbox}
```

but when I use this:

```
\newenvironment{myenv}
{\tcolorbox[ams align]}
  {\endtcolorbox}
```

I get the above error. What is wrong and how can I solve this?

Comment: Why not use `\newtcolorbox{myenv}{ams align}` to define the new environment?

Comment: I need to define an alternative environment to the tcolorbox-environment, for a case where I cannot compile it while loading the tcolorbox package... But I guess that would work. Still the question remains, why this occurs in the first place

Comment: The trouble is that even using (correctly!) the macro form `\tcolorbox` the variable `\@currenvir` containing the name of the current environment is overwritten.

Comment: But it works with option 'hbox'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting an environment `foo` by writing `\begin{foo}` a couple of things happen; among these, the current environment's name is stored in the macro `\@currenvir`, and then the macro `\foo` is expanded. That's the reason why when defining wrappers for environments it's always a good idea to use the internal macros `\foo` and `\endfoo`: in this way you (usually) get clearer error messages.

However, `tcolorbox` does things differently, and the *macro* `\tcolorbox` (more exactly, some other macro a couple of expansions later) also sets `\@currenvir`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}% twocol for smaller snapshot

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\csname@currenvir\endcsname
\begin{center}
\csname@currenvir\endcsname
\end{center}
\csname@currenvir\endcsname
\begin{tcolorbox}
\csname@currenvir\endcsname
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't quite know the rationale behind this choice, but I guess that's (also) why a `tcolorbox` version of `\newenvironment` is provided, namely `\newtcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcolorbox{myenv}{ams align}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
a &= b & c&= d \\
e &= f
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. But does it explain why it works with one option but not with the other?

Comment: @Philipp The mechanism behind `hbox` is completely different. `\hbox` isn't looking for `\end{something}`, so the issue does not present itself in this case.